# Node.js, Mongoose: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'comparePassword')

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

I was attempting to updateUserPassword in my userController.js and came across the following error. Unsure what kind of error this could be. Any input and knowledge would be appreciated.

Getting this error on postman

```
{
    "msg": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'comparePassword')"
}
```

Body

```
{
    "oldPassword":"secret",
    "newPassword":"newsecret"
}
```

userController.js

```
const updateUserPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
  if (!oldPassword || !newPassword) {
    throw new CustomError.BadRequestError('Please provide both values');
  }
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId });

  const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(oldPassword);
  if (!isPasswordValid) {
    throw new CustomError.UnauthenticatedError('Invalid Credentials');
  }
  user.password = newPassword;

  await user.save();
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ msg: 'Success! Password Updated.' });
};
```

Github: https://github.com/k4u5hik/node-express-course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the user is exists or not before calling user.camparePassword, for example:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId });
if (!user) {
  throw new CustomError.UserNotFound();
}
const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(oldPassword);
```

Comment: Currently, there is no functionality to remove user. The user updating the password has to be logged in. So it is safe to assume they would exist in this case.

Comment: PS: I did try adding that code, the error still persists.

Comment: Hello duy le, I did add the code and the issue was resolved today although it did not yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. If it helps you solve the problem, please select my answer as an accepted answer.